# Place image next to text in a DIV

Tags: css, html

Trying to put an image next to a paragraph but it does not seem to work.

This is what I have:

```
<div class="dhn-info-div">
    <p>DEVONSHIRE HOUSE NETWORK IS A <span class="dhn-purple">PEOPLE-FOCUSED</span> MEMBERSHIP CLUB FOR DIRECTOR-LEVEL <span class="dhn-purple">PROFESSIONALS</span> IN LEADERSHIP ROLES WHO HAVE AN INSTINCTIVE FOCUS ON <span class="dhn-purple">THE HUMAN SIDE OF ENTERPRISE..</span></p>            
   <img src="wp-content/themes/expound/images/dhn-directors.png" alt="Devonshire House Network Directors">
   <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.dhn-info-div {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #a20e45;
    width: 95%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dhn-info-div p {
    padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 35px;
    word-spacing: 5px;
}
.dhn-info-div img {
    float: right;
}
```

Image has to be on the right of the text. The div shouldn't be 100% in size. Cheers

This is how I want it to look:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPxbB.png

Comment: Do you wish to wrap the text around the image or have a column of text next to the image?

Comment: what's the width and height of image?

Comment: please look at the link to the final product. Width is 450 but should be responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on if you want to wrap the text around the image or have 2 columns, here’s both solutions:

1. If you want to wrap the text around the image it needs to be within the `p` tag. [See example](http://jsfiddle.net/4nESD/) (I have also added 10px padding around the image).
2. If you want 2 columns you need to define the width of both so they fit in. I have also added `float: left;` to both and some padding to the image to make it look slightly better. [See example](http://jsfiddle.net/4nESD/1/)

Comment: Following your example I had to leave the image to float right and add width to the div. Then also set margin to 0 for img. This gave me what I was after. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t978L/)

You needed to add some `width` to some elements such as the text
also you had no `width` or `height` on your image.

I also added `top:40px;` to your image to bring it down to the level of the text

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the `<img>` in your `<p>` at top? that would fix it:

```
<div class="dhn-info-div">
    <p>
        <img src="wp-content/themes/expound/images/dhn-directors.png" alt="Devonshire House Network Directors" />
        DEVONSHIRE HOUSE NETWORK IS A <span class="dhn-purple">PEOPLE-FOCUSED</span> MEMBERSHIP CLUB FOR DIRECTOR-LEVEL <span class="dhn-purple">PROFESSIONALS</span> IN LEADERSHIP ROLES WHO HAVE AN INSTINCTIVE FOCUS ON <span class="dhn-purple">THE HUMAN SIDE OF ENTERPRISE..</span>

    </p>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: is now responsive!

i made this fiddle, check it http://jsfiddle.net/fYh7u/

you can wrap the text in a div, and the image in another div, inside the main div "dnh-info-div", in my example i miss the "div", at end of class, because is obvious.

HTML:

```
<div class="dhn-info">
<div class="dhn-text">
    <p>devonshire house network is a <span class="text-purple">people-focused</span> membership club for director-level <span class="text-purple">professionals</span> in leadership roles who have an <span class="text-purple">instinctive focus</span> on <span class="text-purple">the human side of enterprise.</span></p>
</div>
<div class="dhn-img">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kzJiOjx.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dhn-info {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #a20e45;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dhn-info .dhn-text {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px 10px 0px 35px;
}
.dhn-info .dhn-text p {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    word-spacing: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}
.dhn-info .dhn-img {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}

.dhn-info .dhn-text p > span.text-purple {
    color: #9b59b6;
}
.dhn-info .dhn-img img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```